# Socket Err 10013 with Uno Platform apps

Tags: c#, sockets, uno-platform

I have a Beamer in my network and my laptop.

I made a console App to turn the beamer on/off via TCP/IP protocol and it works fine.

Now I want a fancy Uno GUI with the same code behind but surprisingly now I get an Socket exception:

> 10013: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

I have googled 3 days straight and tryed very many things indluding

- Firewall settings/turn offs
- Permission Group editing
- weird code i rly couldnt untestand.
  im using Visual Studio 2019
  Code below if someone needs it:

I would be very thankfull if someone can help me with that.

Here a code comparison:

1. Console Code:

   ```
    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Text;

    namespace Test
    {
        class Programm
        {
            static void Main(String[] args)
            {

        Console.WriteLine("START Enter");
        Console.ReadLine();

        const int Port = 7142;
        const string IPv4 = "192.168.10.70";


        IPAddress ipo = IPAddress.Parse(IPv4);
        IPEndPoint ipEo = new IPEndPoint(ipo, Port);

        var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipo, Port);
        var socket = new Socket(endpoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        Console.WriteLine("Verbindung wird Aufgebaut mit");
        Console.WriteLine("Adresse: " + IPv4);
        Console.WriteLine("Port: " + Port);

        try
        {
            socket.Connect(endpoint);
        }
        catch(SocketException se)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Verbindung Gescheitert");
            Console.WriteLine(se.ErrorCode + ": " + se.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }



        Console.WriteLine("Verbindung hergestellt");
        Console.WriteLine("Befehl senden?");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Befehl wird gesendet");


        var networkstream = new NetworkStream(socket, true);


        var msg = "\x02\x01\x00\x00\x00\x03";


        var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);


        foreach (int i in buffer)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} ", i);
        }


        networkstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        var response = new byte[1024];
        var bytesRead = networkstream.Read(response, 0, response.Length);
        var responseStr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Empfangen wurde:");

        foreach (int i in response)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} ", i);
        }


        Console.ReadLine();


    }
   }
   }
   ```
2. Now the UNO App Code:

   ```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
    using Windows.Foundation;
    using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

    using System.Text;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Net;


    namespace Test
    { 



        public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
        {


            public MainPage()
            {
                this.InitializeComponent();



            }

            public void Ein_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
        const int Port = 7142;
        const string IPv4 = "192.168.10.70";


        IPAddress ipo = IPAddress.Parse(IPv4);
        IPEndPoint ipEo = new IPEndPoint(ipo, Port);

        var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipo, Port);
        var socket = new Socket(endpoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        try
        {
            socket.Connect(endpoint);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Verbindung Wurde aufgebaut");
            var networkstream = new NetworkStream(socket, true);
            var msg = "\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02";
            var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);
            networkstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            socket.Disconnect(true);
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {


            Testblock1.Text = se.ErrorCode + ": " + se.Message;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Verbindung Gescheitert");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(se.ErrorCode + ": " + se.Message);
        }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are targeting a local network IP address, which requires a special permission to be declared in your UWP app project. In the UWP project there should be a `Package.appxmanifest` file. Double-click it and select the **Capabilities** tab. Then in the list below check the box next to **Private Networks (Client & Server)**.

[image: Package.Manifest capabilities]

Comment: Perfect you are my Hero!! It Works! Thank you and have a great Week! :D

Comment: I am glad it helped :-) ! Happy coding!